# StackedBarChart from modern UI

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, user-interface

I wanna add to my tool a statistics window that will contain stacked bars chart.

I used for a similar application Modern UI (Metro) charts to create a single graph and it worked fine.

This Time, I need to show an unknown number of StackedBarChart and I'm having problems doing so.

 I'd like your thoughts for a solution or a work-around

this is what my code for a single chart looks like (*which works fine*):

```
<chart:StackedBarChart  Width="400" Height="400" ChartTitle="Statistics" ChartSubTitle="A single stacked bar">
        <chart:StackedBarChart.Series>
            <chart:ChartSeries 
                SeriesTitle="Y axis name"
                DisplayMember="Name"
                ValueMember="Number" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObservableCollectionOfNamesAndNumbers}"/>
        </chart:StackedBarChart.Series>
</chart:StackedBarChart>
```

and what i want to do is something like this (using *itemsSource*):

```
<chart:StackedBarChart  Width="400" Height="400" ChartTitle="Statistics" ChartSubTitle="Multiple stacked bars">
        <chart:StackedBarChart.Series ItemsSource="{SomeObservableCollectionOfSomeObservableCollectionOfNamesAndNumbers}">
            <chart:ChartSeries 
                SeriesTitle="{binding SomeObservableCollectionOfNamesAndNumbers.Name}"
                DisplayMember="Name"
                ValueMember="Number" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObservableCollectionOfNamesAndNumbers}"/>
        </chart:StackedBarChart.Series>
</chart:StackedBarChart>
```

but unfortunately it is not possible, can you think of any other way?

Answer (score 1):

you have to bind Series to your Observable Collection like this:

```
chart:StackedColumnChart ChartTitle="Statistics" ChartSubTitle="Multiple stacked bars" Series="{Binding Bars}">
    </chart:StackedColumnChart>
```

You have to define your series in the Observable Collection (Bars in this case) in your Code Behind/ViewModel

```
ObservableCollection<TestClass> blocks = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>(); 
ChartSeries chartSerie = new ChartSeries();
            chartSerie.SeriesTitle = "Some Title"
            chartSerie.DisplayMember = "Category";
            chartSerie.ValueMember = "Number";
            Bars.Add(chartSerie);
            chartSerie.ItemsSource = blocks;
            blocks = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
```

Blocks are holding the single stacks and a ChartSerie is one whole Bar. 
The TestClass holds your values and looks like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Feel free to ask, if you need any further information.